# Trigger to update Campaign Member status from Lead field

Tags: apex, trigger

Can someone help me figure out why this trigger isn't working? This is what I would like it to do:

When ABCStage on Lead gets changed to "Not Interested" and if the Lead is part of CampaignXYZ, I would like to change the CampaignMember Status to Responded.

This is what I have right now:

```
trigger CMStatus on Lead (after insert, after update){

  List<ID> LeadIds = New List<ID>();

  for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

    if(l.ABC_Stage__c == 'Not Interested')
    {
      LeadIds.add(l.Id);
    }
  }

  List<CampaignMember> cmList = [SELECT id, status FROM CampaignMember WHERE id in :LeadIds];

  for(CampaignMember cm : cmList)
  {
     cm.status = 'Responded';
  }

  update cmList;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have an easy-to-make mistake, actually. You meant to filter by *LeadId*, not *Id*.

```
trigger CMStatus on Lead (after insert, after update){

  List<ID> LeadIds = New List<ID>();

  for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

    if(l.ABC_Stage__c == 'Not Interested')
    {
      LeadIds.add(l.Id);
    }
  }

  List<CampaignMember> cmList = [SELECT id, status FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadId in :LeadIds];

  for(CampaignMember cm : cmList)
  {
     cm.status = 'Responded';
  }

  update cmList;
}
```